# AmazonSES sending emails to multiple people when only one person is included in the Destination field

Tags: java, amazon-ses

I'm working on sending transactional emails with AmazonSES. I'm noticing that when two `SendEmailRequests` are made within a couple of minutes from each other, AmazonSES sends the first email correctly. But the second email includes both email addresses in the **to** field.

For example, if I'm sending two emails, one to `janeDoe@gmail.com` and another to `jamesSmith@gmail.com`. In the email sent to `janeDoe@gmail.com` she will see that the email has been sent just to her. But `jamesSmith@gmail.com` will see that the email has been sent to him and `janeDoe@gmail.com`.

In other words, Jane (the first receiver) is receiving an email that was meant only for James (the second receiver) to see.

#### Code for email sending

```
sendEmailRequest
        .withDestination(
                destination.withToAddresses(to))
        .withMessage(message
                .withBody(body
                        .withHtml(new Content()
                                .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(htmlBody))
                        .withText(new Content()
                                .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(textBody)))
                .withSubject(new Content()
                        .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
        .withSource(from);

amazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a glitch in AmazonSES?

Comment: The simpler explanation could be that your code is creating a `sendEmailRequest` with both email addresses rather than a such a critical error in Amazon SES.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I would guess that you're incorrectly reusing some object (e.g. `sendEmailRequest`, or maybe `destination`), which results in data from the previous send to still be present.

Comment: That was exactly the problem @Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 2):

## The root cause of the problem

- The main cause of the problem was that I seemed to be re-using instances of `Destination` object instead of instantiating new instances of `Destination` object for every `sendEmailRequest`

**Why was I re-using instances?**

- Well I made a **@Configuration** module that provides a bean for `Destination` object with spring.
- I autowired the `Destination` object so Spring will handle the dependancy injection for me. What im guessing is that from each `sendEmailRequest` spring is injecting the same instane of the `Destination` object. This resulted in my problem and which was why I thought it was a problem on AmazonSES's side.

## All in all

#### DONT do this

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    @Autowired
    AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailServiceClient;

    @Autowired
    SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest;

    @Autowired
    Destination destination;

    @Autowired
    Message message;

    @Autowired
    Body body;

    public void sendEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String htmlBody, String textBody) throws CouldNotSendEmailException {
        try {
            sendEmailRequest
                    .withDestination(
                            destination.withToAddresses(to))
                    .withMessage(message
                            .withBody(body
                                    .withHtml(new Content()
                                            .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(htmlBody))
                                    .withText(new Content()
                                            .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(textBody)))
                            .withSubject(new Content()
                                    .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
                    .withSource(from);

            amazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CouldNotSendEmailException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

 
}
```

#### Do this instead (notice the "new Destination()")

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    @Autowired
    AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailServiceClient;

    @Autowired
    SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest;

    @Autowired
    Message message;

    @Autowired
    Body body;

    public void sendEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String htmlBody, String textBody) throws CouldNotSendEmailException {
        try {
            sendEmailRequest
                    .withDestination(
                            new Destination().withToAddresses(to))
                    .withMessage(message
                            .withBody(body
                                    .withHtml(new Content()
                                            .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(htmlBody))
                                    .withText(new Content()
                                            .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(textBody)))
                            .withSubject(new Content()
                                    .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
                    .withSource(from);

            amazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CouldNotSendEmailException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

 
}
```

Comment: Given [`SendEmailRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/model/SendEmailRequest.html) is documented as _"Represents a request to send a **single** formatted email using Amazon SES"_ (emphasis mine), you also need to create a new `SendEmailRequest` for each request. Right now, if `EmailService.sendEmail` is called concurrently, you can produce wrong emails as well. So, remove the bean, and use `new SendEmailRequest()` in your `sendEmail` message.